# yii2 GoogleOAuth successfull redirect to 404

Tags: php, yii2, google-oauth

I'm using yii2-authclient for user login

```
 'authClientCollection' => [
      'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
      'clients' => [
          'google' => [
              'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
              'clientId' => '*********',
              'clientSecret' => '*********',
              'returnUrl'=>'http://mywebsite/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/auth?authclient=google',

          ],
```

and in the controller :

```
'auth' => [
     'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
     'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'
],
```

but after redirect from google to http://mywebsite/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/auth?authclient=google'
it shows error
Not Found (#404)

Comment: Your config `returnUrl` should be: `'returnUrl'=>'http://mywebsite/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/auth&authclient=google',`

Comment: Did you double check that this url actually works if invoked manually? There could be any kind of internal server error or forbidden but should not return a `404`. Also double check your URL rules both in app `config.php` and server config. If you have logging enabled have a look at `runtime/logs/app.log` as well,

Answer (score 1):

I have used following code in SecurityController and its working fine in my case so Can check following code ?

```
public function actions()
{
    
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'auth' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}

public function onAuthSuccess($client)
{
     write your success code here.
}
```